Hide Description field for custom taxonomy?
There is a custom taxonomy created in WordPress
<?php
function create_works_category_taxonomy() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'              => 'Works Categories',
        'singular_name'     => 'Works Category',
        'search_items'      => 'Search Works Categories',
        'all_items'         => 'All Works Categories',
        'parent_item'       => 'Parent Works Category',
        'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent Works Category:',
        'edit_item'         => 'Edit Works Category',
        'update_item'       => 'Update Works Category',
        'add_new_item'      => 'Add New Works Category',
        'new_item_name'     => 'New Works Category Name',
        'menu_name'         => 'Works Categories',
    );

    $args = array(
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'works-category' ),
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'works-category', 'page', $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'create_works_category_taxonomy' );

Question - Is there any filter/hook that would not display the main content field Description by default for a given taxonomy ?

*I understand that you can use CSS/JS, but I would like to know if there is a cleaner solution ?

The term edit view uses edit-tag-form.php to render the editing form. The description field is hard-coded in the file without any filters or actions to control its visibility. So I'm afraid you'll have to resort to css/js solutions.
If you're feeling adventurous, you could disable the default UI for the custom taxonomy, register custom submenu pages for listing and editing the terms, and handle the CRUD operations for the terms on those pages with a custom form.

It's sad. I was hoping there was some way to disable this field for site editors without CSS/JS.
